# DateTime.TryParse string in wrong format

Tags: c#, sql-server, parsing, datetime

in C# I'm trying to do a DateTime.TryParse on a string field which I am getting from a DataFeed which I know is in "MM/dd/YYYY" format. e.g.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.TryParse("01/30/11");
```

Only thing is now "dt" is in the incorrect format to be stored into my Database which has a DateTime locale setting of "dd/MM/YYYY".

How do I go about parsing the string field correctly into dt and then into my DB?  What would be the best way to handle this?  If I set the globalization of my CurrentThread to en-US, then dt would be in en-US format, however when inserting into the DB, it is still incorrectly stored? :S

Thanks

David

Comment: MS SQL server shouldn't really care what the format is. If you're passing dt itself you should be fine.

Comment: `dt` is in no format at all. It is a `DateTime`, and that has no inherent string representation.

Comment: how is it being stored in the database. the problem does not lie with `TryParse`.

Comment: Read the comments here and give us more information...

Comment: Thank you guys, to give more information, I think it has something to do with the culture on my machine not being set??? however I have tried using System.Globalization, maybe I am not setting something right?

I receive a string from a DataFeed which supposed to represent the Date, the date is for example, "07/08/2011" (MM/dd/YYYY), however it appears to me that DateTime culture is set to dd/MM/YYYY format, so even though the parse works, it's mixed up the Month and Day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("15/12/2011", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you want to convert the DateTime value to a string back, use the following code:

```
string dtString = string.Format("{0: dd/MM/yyyy}", dt);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your code sample, my date is not 15/12/2011, it is 12/15/2011, but I want it to be parsed into dt as 15/12/2011 ???

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to convert a string to a DateTime value, right?  The string stores data in the "dd/MM/yyyy" format, right?  If so, try the code, I posted.  You will see, that the DateTime value will contain 15 december 2011.

Comment: yes, I do want to convert a string to a DateTime value, however, the string that I have is "12/15/2011" and I need it to convert to DateTime with "15/12/2011" to be stored in the DB

Comment: thanks for your update, I don't want to convert a DateTime value back to a string.  My problem is I want to force a DateTime value with dd/MM/YYYY format to read in a string with a MM/dd/YYYY format and get it right, understand that the string I am providing is in MM/dd/YYYY format and convert it to it's DateTime dd/MM/YYYY format

Comment: DateTime is a struct, it is not a string.  So, the struct generally, cannot have formatting.  Format is used to represent this struct as a string.  Based on this, please tell me, what does not work in the code above.

Comment: if you want, we can discuss this in chat

Comment: @platon let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1270/discussion-between-davidt07-and-platon)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `TryParseExact`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx

Comment: Did that, still didn't work, do you have an example?  Maybe I'm setting the Culture info incorrectly?

Comment: This didn't work for example, CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US"); bool dateValue = DateTime.TryParseExact("01/30/2011", "dd/MM/YYYY", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out dtDateTime)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you understand, the TryParse be made by the if statement, see the following example,

```
  private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DateTime myData = new DateTime();

        if (DateTime.TryParse(this.textBox1.Text,out myData))
        {
            // your filed db = myData
        }
    }
```

you then enter in the block if the update of the database field, according to the cultures set on your PC.

Bye